# SAS 9361-4i - One drive stuck in UB state

Tags: raid

Just got a new SuperMicro box in the rack. 1U and four drives
The RAID control is set to RAID 10 - booted it up and two drives showed as failed. Reset both of them and it ran a rebuild. One drive stayed online, the other kept returning to failed. Replaced this one with the cold spare - it now shows a state of UB and I cannot make any changes to it from within the BIOS configuration Utility - the only selectable menu option is 'show' - which actually does nothing.

[image]
I have known these BIOS Config Utilities to be a little flaky and prefer the Intel Utility - but of course I need an OS for that, and don't want to install that whilst the RAID is degraded.
Any ideas how I can get this new drive online?
Thanks

==== EDIT ==================

The only available option from 'F2' is 'Locate'

[image]

I should also add, that when the original drive kept going into 'failed' I pulled it out and back in again. This showed up as UB, but 'Make unconfigured good' was available. I selected that and the utility froze. Tried to reboot, but it wouldn't get past the MegaRAID BIOS (got to 100% and hung). Replaced the drive with the cold spare and now I can get back into the config utility...

Comment: UB means Unconfigured Bad. That doesn't necessarily mean the drive is bad; it can also be placed in this state if manually forced offline. You should press F2 at this point and review the available operations.

Comment: 'Locate' is the actual term - that is all that can be selected from F2

Comment: You definitely should do that, then. If it fails, then you just might have a bad drive after all.

Comment: Do what? Locate should show you where the drive is, but doesn't appear to do anything. What are the chances, even for Seagate, of having two brand new bad drives?

Comment: Oh right, that just blinks the light. Nevermind. Not enough coffee yet this morning.

Comment: I would suggest removing and reinserting the disk. But be aware that these controllers have a failure history where they remember drives they think have failed. You may need to find that option (Maintain PD Fail History) and turn it off temporarily, before removing and reinserting the drive. If you still get no operations for the drive, then either it, or the cable, or the controller is bad.

Comment: Tried all that still the same! I can have a go at reseating the card, the cables and resetting the RAID from scratch - when I get the chance to pull it out again. Sigh

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, no idea what's going on. Going to take the disk out and plug it into another machine and investigate. Disk is practically brand new.

Comment: Swap the cable for slots 0 and 1 (or whatever your problem drive is) and see if the error migrates. If it does it's not the RAID controller, then it's down to cable or backplane. In my case it was the cable